# Subscript type for remove an Array column from index in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

What kind of object can I use as an index argument to remove columns from an n-dim array?

```
deleteCol <- function(array,col_to_del,in_dim){
    index <- vector(mode='list', length=length(dim(array)))
    index[in_dim] <- -col_to_del
    return(array[index, drop = FALSE])
}
```

I want to make a function that removes a specific column from an array, and I want to make this work for any n-dimension arrays. I already know that lists aren't accepted as index arguments, but matrix does. The code is just to show what I want to do. I don't find that an index matrix does the job because I can't enter negative or NULL values required for indexes like " , , ... , -n, ... ,".

I try to make an index matrix, but it doesn't accept negative elements, nor does it have an element to leave an empty position.

Comment: I might be missing the point, but a column should always be the 2nd dimension in an array - does `a[,-1,,drop=FALSE]` for instance do what you want where `a` is an n-dim array?

Comment: @thelatemail that wont work for `n-dimensional` array but for a `3-dim` array

Comment: Logical vectors are acceptable. If you do not want the Nth item then this index should succeed. `logic<-logical(nrow);logi[N] <- FALSE`. So I was thinking matrix, but this should apply to arrays as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extraordinarily ugly, but here's a way to pass the empty arguments to drop columns programmatically from an n-dimensional array:

```
a <- array(1:32, dim=c(2,2,2,2))
dim(a)
##[1] 2 2 2 2
qeo <- list(quote(expr=))
args <- c(qeo, -1, rep(qeo, length(dim(a))-2), drop = FALSE)
out <- do.call(`[`, c(list(a), args))
dim(out)
##[1] 2 1 2 2
```

Put into a flexible function by @magavich, from the comments:

```
removecol <- function(array, col_to_del, in_dim){   
    qeo <- list(quote(expr=))
    qeo <- rep(qeo, length(dim(array)))
    qeo[in_dim] <- -col_to_del
    args <- c(qeo, drop = FALSE)
    do.call(`[`, c(list(array), args))
}
```

Comment: It works! I just add a line to have control of the dim and the index. Tanks!
```R
removecol <- function(array, col_to_del,in_dim){
  qeo <- list(quote(expr=))
  qeo <- rep(qeo, length(dim(array)))
  qeo[in_dim] <- -col_to_del
  args <- c(qeo, drop = FALSE)
  out <- do.call(`[`, c(list(array), args))
  return(out)
}
```